# WebView erased after fragment replace

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

In my app i have fragment which contains WebView. On first createView i'm loading URL. Now what i want to achieve is to not load it again after i replace this fragment with another and then come back.

I have tried to override onPause method and run saveState(bundle) then in createView run restoreState(bundle) but it seem to not work for me. Screen is blank or it takes very long time to display result.

Is there any other way to do it? Loading same URL over and over again is kinda annoying so i would like to avoid it.

With best regards.

Comment: Instead of replacing the fragment, have you tried show/hide a fragment?

Comment: I have made it as you suggested. Though to not keep all fragments i have made 2 linear layouts with fragment on each one of them. Now when i need fragments with webview i just make first linearlayout gone and second one visible. But i have weird problem. When i change from Layout with WebView to Layout with other fragment sometimes webview fragment gets erased. Just like i have never made .add transaction.